# How do I increase the Windows open file open used by _open_osfhandle?

Tags: c, windows, posix

In Windows, how do I increase the open file limit used by `_open_osfhandle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is 512, but you can change that using the [_setmaxstdio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e3b887c.aspx) function.